# Find an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)/\bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

Consider $p$ is a prime, the principal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $p$ denoted by $(p)$, the direct product $\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ and the direct sum $\bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ run over all primes.

Find  an injective $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathscr{A}$, where 
$$\mathscr{A}=\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)/\bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p),$$ 
that is, a quotient $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $\varphi:\mathbb Q\to\mathscr A$ for integer $n$ as
$$\varphi(n)= [[n]_2,[n]_3,[n]_5,\ldots].$$
Then note $\varphi(n)$ is invertible in $\mathscr A$. Indeed, each $\mathbb Z/(p)$ is a field, so we can define the $p$-th component of $\varphi\left (\frac 1n\right)$ to $[n^{-1}]_p$ if $p\nmid n$, and $0$ otherwise.

It's trivially checked that $\varphi$ is an injective $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism.

**Remark.** Actually $\bigoplus_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is the torsion subgroup of $\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}/(p)$, so $\mathscr A$ is torsion-free and divisible abelian group, and by well-known theorem it is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.